# Uploading image to cloudinary using Express.js, throws an error

Tags: javascript, express, cloudinary

The error

[image]

I am having an issue when trying to upload the image to cloudinary using Express.js. I have seen similar questions here, but ***NONE*** of the answers worked for me. Could assist me with this issue?

here is my code

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config()

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
})

exports.uploads = async (file, folder) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-catch
  try {
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, {
      use_filename: true,
      folder
    })

    return {
      url: result.url,
      id: result.public_id
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

multer.js

```
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

const UPLOADS_DIR = './uploads'

if (!fs.existsSync(UPLOADS_DIR)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(UPLOADS_DIR)
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, UPLOADS_DIR)
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')
    const originalname = file.originalname || 'unknown'
    cb(null, `${timestamp}-${originalname}`)
  }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true)
  } else {
    // reject file
    cb({ message: 'Unsupported file format' }, false)
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 },
  fileFilter
})

module.exports = upload
```

here is my ProductController.js, where I upload the image then push the link to the database

```
const createProduct = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, price, description } = req.body

  console.log('Received request with data:', { name, price, description })

  const uploader = async (path) => await cloudinary.uploads(path, 'Images')

  try {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const urls = []
      const files = req.files
      for (const file of files) {
        const { path } = file
        const newPath = await uploader(path)
        urls.push(newPath)
        fs.unlinkSync(path)
      }

      console.log('Cloudinary Upload URLs:', urls)
      // creating the product
      const product = await new Product({
        name,
        description,
        price,
        files: urls
      })

      await product.save()
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'product created sucessfully',
        data: product
      })
    } else {
      return res.status(405).json({
        err: `${req.method} method not allowed`
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating product:', error)
    return res.status(412).send({
      success: false,
      message: error.message
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please search your error first](https://www.google.com/search?q=unable+to+verify+leaf+signature+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan i have searched and found 3-4 answers, but those answers didn't help. thats why i wrote "NONE of the answers worked for me"

Comment: Could be cloudinary not having a good enough cert for your node. Could be node too old to understand the newer cert. Make sure you have a version of node that is actually compatible with cloudinary. For example node 21 does not handle deflate well because of an issue with zlib in node's native fetch.

Comment: The error in the screenshot isn't directly related to Cloudinary as far as I can see, though as mplungjan mentioned it could be that your application environment has an old certificate store or old libraries that can't support something about the response.  Assuming it's indeed related to your application accepting the certificate and that you've ruled out the problem being due to a firewall or security system on your side, the cert I receive for api.cloudinary.com was signed by `Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2` - http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/

Comment: @Igy was right i had an issue on my side, i was getting this error due to the firewall. once i tried at home, everything was working fine. Thank you